# mlUnitTest not working for MarkLogic Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I have setup the UnitTetsing Framework for Marklogic using the below url-

https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-unit-test

I am able to deploy my project using `mlDeploy` and able to load my Testing module using `mlUnitTestLoadModules` but while running the test cases from gradle `mlUnitTest` i am getting the below error-

```
Task ':mlUnitTest' is not up-to-date because:
Task has not declared any outputs.
Releasing connection

:mlUnitTest (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 16,5,main]) completed. Took 0.064 secs


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mlUnitTest'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Any Suggestions ??

Comment: Can you run "gradle mlUnitTest --stacktrace" and post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue come up recently when migrating to marklogic-unit-test-1.0.0.  There is a work around thanks to one of the MarkLogic gurus.   If this is still an
issue let us know.